# Xavier and he_normal initialization difference

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, initialization

What is the difference between He normal and Xavier normal initializer in keras. Both seem to initialize weights based on variance in the input data. Any intuitive explanation for the difference between both?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a programming question, it is more suited to stats or data science SE.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See [this discussion on Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/319849/130598):

> In summary, the main difference for machine learning practitioners is the following:
>
> - He initialization works better for layers with ReLu activation.
> - Xavier initialization works better for layers with sigmoid activation.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: Should I use He initialization if there is a batch normalization between input and relu ?

Comment: Reg. Xavier, it should be tanh specifically, not logistic sigmoid. Both tanh and logistic sigmoid are sigmoidal functions, but usually "sigmoid" means "logistic sigmoid"

Answer (score 4):

**Weight (kernel) Initialization** parameters for each **type of activation function**:

1. Xavier/Glorot Initialization:    None, hyperbolic Tan (tanh),
   Logistic(sigmoid), softmax.
2. He Initialization:    Rectified Linear activation unit(ReLU) and
   Variants.
3. LeCun Initialization:    Scaled Exponential Linear Unit(SELU)

Application...

```
keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal")
```

Here's a link to the research paper by *Xavier Glorot, Yoshua Bengio* on "Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks", incase you want to understand the importance and the math behind weight initialization.
http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a.html